# Displaying error messages onChange in redux-form

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, redux-form

I'm trying to use redux-form Field (together with Material-ui) and validation. It appears that the error messages are shown when I navigate away from the field (i.e. onBlur). What I would like to achieve is to do validation on the fly as the user types, and display error messages onChange event. How would I go about achieving this behavior?

```
import { TextField } from 'redux-form-material-ui';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

const MyForm = (props) => (
  <form>
      <div className="form-group">
        <Field
          name="foo"
          type="text"
          hintText="Foo"
          component={TextField}
        />
  </form>
);

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'MyForm',  
  validate             
})(MyForm);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you played with the example in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nKlYo387)? Like Dennis suggested, you could call "touch", though depending on your need you may choose to do this onChange:

```
  <Field
    name="username"
    type="text"
    component={renderField}
    label="Username"
    onChange={() => touch('username')}
  />
```

Answer (score 4):

The default behaviour of validation is that messages are only displayed when fields are touched (i.e. onBlur).

I suppose you could work around that by using the touch method in componentWillMount, so that it becomes touched upon mount:

```
componentWillMount() {
  const { touch } = this.props;
  touch('foo');
}
```

That does however have the drawback of possibly showing any errors directly when the form is loaded, but in this case validation is triggered in onChange right away.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, this indeed could have been an option. I ended up just accessing the state via redux-form's formValueSelector, validating on the fly and setting Field's errorText directly. Seems to accomplish what I want.